# The property 'PersonalizedAds' was not found in type 'MTAdView

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, admob

I have installed [MarcTron.Admob](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MarcTron.Admob/) package, version 1.6.9 for my Xamarin.Forms project.

According to its documentation there is a property called `PersonalizedAds`.

1. I get the error: `The property 'PersonalizedAds' was not found in type 'MTAdView'`. Why is the property not recognized?
2. Using `CrossMTAdmob.Current.UserPersonalizedAds = true;` which MTAdview items would it affect? All the MTAdview items that are listed in a Content Page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I get the error: The property 'PersonalizedAds' was not found in type 'MTAdView'. Why is the property not recognized?

The Personalized property was removed from MTAdViewfrom MTAdView Version 1.6.2. If you want to use it, use Version 1.6.1 and the previous version.

> Using CrossMTAdmob.Current.UserPersonalizedAds = true; which MTAdview items would it affect? All the MTAdview items that are listed in a Content Page?

`UserPersonalizedAds` is Global Property. When you set `UserPersonalizedAds` to true, all your Admob banner will show personalized ads and will have the same Id.

Comment: If `PersonalizedAds` is truly removed, which obviously is the case, they should also remove it from the documentation. Your wrote: "When you set `UserPersonalizedAds` to true, all your Admob banner will show personalized ads and will have the same Id." What do you mean the will have the same ID? What if I have 2 different banners with different `AdsId` property in the same Content Page?

Comment: When we set the `CrossMTAdmob.Current.UserPersonalizedAds = true;`, we also set the ID like below: `CrossMTAdmob.Current.AdsId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";`. In this case all your Admob banner will show personalized ads and will have the same Id.

Comment: OK. I guess though that `UserPersonalizedAds` could get set once for all the ads of the app.

Comment: Glad to help. If you have any issue about this, feel free to let me know.